# Does Stein's (1952) theorem not work in a special case?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Stein's (1952) theorem states:

> "A necessary and sufficient condition that B is convergent, is that there exists a positive definite Hermitian matrix H for which H-B*HB is positive definite"

where B* denotes the conjugate transpose of B.

However, take:
$$B=\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        0.9 & 0  \\
        0 & 0.3 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$$
Which is convergent. And take:
$$H=\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        0.8 & 0.3  \\
        0.3 & 0.2 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$$
Which is positive semidefinite. Then, 
$$H-B^*HB=\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        0.152 & 0.219  \\
        0.219 & 0.182 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$$
But this matrix is not positive definite. The theorem seems to say that the positive definiteness of H-B*HB is a necessary condition for B to be convergent. I know I am making a logical mistake, but I'd appreciate your help in pointing it out. Thanks.

Comment: The theorem says that such an $H$ exists, not that $H - B^*HB$ will be positive definite for all Hermitian matrices $H$.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem only says that such an $H$ exists, not that $H - B^*HB$ will be positive definite for all Hermitian matrices $H$.

For an example of an Hermitian $H$ for which $H - B^*HB$ is positive definite, we may simply take 
$$
H = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$